# g++ does not show a 'unused' warning

Tags: c++, g++

I have a little piece of code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i=0;
    istream_iterator<string> EOS;
    double x;

    return 0;
}
```

Now i compile it with my g++ (GCC) 4.4.4

```
g++ -W -Wall -pedantic test.cc -o test
```

And get:

```
test.cc: In function 'int main()':
test.cc:9: warning: unused variable 'i'
test.cc:11: warning: unused variable 'x'
```

Why there is no warning for unused EOS?

Comment: FACT: `EOS` **is not** `lock_guard` or any kind of variable to be used with the sole purpose of the effect of its destructor, and this is what happens most of the time, with `std::string`, etc. So, there indeed should have been a warning there, so that the user notice that it can eliminate the variable, in this sense, what's the big  difference between unused `std::string` vs unused `int` at a high level? None. This is a design issue in C++.

Comment: @pepper_chico the compiler has to get *very* clever to deduce that whilst `~istream_iterator<string>()` is not trivial, eliding *both* `istream_iterator<string>()` *and* `~istream_iterator<string>()` has the same result as leaving them in. In the general case, such cleverness is **impossible**, so there has to be a point where the analysis stops early

Comment: @Caleth those are the implementation details. I was pointing at the language issue at a high level, where you want a simple response, when you look at the code, for the question: "is this not explicitly used by the programmer?". You can answer it, but a C++ compiler can't, since it only sees "use" as defined by the language, which considers destructors, which is irrelevant for the question posed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is not a primitive value, so its constructor and/or destructor might have desired side effects.

To illustrate that this happens in practice: I use a class to time sections of code, that looks roughly like this:

```
class Timed {
    double start;
    public:
        Timed() { start = now(); }
        ~Timed() { std::cout << (now() - start) << '\n'; }
}
```

So to measure how long a function takes, I simply do:

```
void slow() {
    Timed t;
    // heavy operation here...
}
```

The variable `t` never gets used, but it's still important to the behaviour of the code.

Comment: +1 For using destructor to calculate the end of timing.  Cool trick.

Comment: It's called RIAA and has been a design goal since inception of C++ (see Bjarne Stroustrup)

Comment: @sehe You probably ment RAII :-) didn't you?

Comment: @Kylo: Yup - sry. Should've looked that up

Comment: This reminds me of performance tracking :) https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp#performance-tracking that uses same mechanism to track performance of function / blocks (Disclaimer: I am developer of this lib) -- woops just noticed this thread is pretty old :) Long live SO

Answer (score 7):

`istream_iterator<string>` has a constructor, so the declaration of `EOS` isn't really a no-op like the declarations of `i` and `x` are.

Often you want to declare a class-type object and then not do anything with it.  For example, consider `std::lock_guard` in C++0x (`boost::scoped_lock` in Boost) or any other kind of scope guard class.  You don't usually want to do anything with that kind of object, you just want to create the object so that its destructor get run at the end of the block to perform whatever cleanup needs to be performed.

Answer (score 4):

Because you could have done that with a purpose. It's not a primitive. Maybe the constructor and destructor do something important?

MFC even had classes that operated that way, you could do this:

```
void foo()
{
    CWaitCursor cursor;

    [...]
}
```

That would display an hourglass icon for the duration of the function.