# Why is "unused variable" warning not reported for all variables?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unused-variables

I have this code:

```
// initializer lists
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int values[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::vector<int> v { 4, 5, 6 };

    std::vector<std::string> cities {
        "London", "New York", "Paris", "Tokio"
    };

    return 0;
}
```

However the `gcc` compiler gives me `unused variable` warning only for `values` array. Why `v` and `cities` is not reported?

Comment: because they are not a POD?

Comment: Those two are class instances and class constructors/destructors might have side effects, e.g. alter some global state.

Comment: The latter two variables *are* used (in their own construction with potential side effects therein). The trivial POD-types undergoes no such functional construction. The identical usage warning will happen for your others if you change their types to POD-types and, for example, initialize them dynamically. `std::vector<int> *pv = new std::vector<int>{ 4,5,6 };` will issue the identical warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a primitive value, so its constructor and/or destructor might have desired side effects.

Classical example: a *Timer object* which measures the time between its construction and destruction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302868/1938163

Comment: Or a scoped lock object.