# Why is no 'unused variable' warning given for boost::scoped_lock instances?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-warnings

I have my build configured to give compiler warnings for unused variables. I use scoped_locks liberally in my code, and am curious as to how local instances of scoped locks circumvent the warning.

So my question is, why do boost::scoped_lock's not generate an unused variable compiler warning?

Example code:

```
void myFunc() {
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_mutex) // no compiler warning
  var a;  // Compiler warning
}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302848/g-does-not-show-a-unused-warning or something similar, since I found it kind of hard to find the answer in what's currently linked.

Comment: You're right. This has been answered.

Comment: The link provided by Ivan Vergiliev has a better answer than the duplicate issue cited by dasblinkenlight.