# G++ not removing static class instance

Tags: c++, g++

**toolchain** : arm-none-eabi-gcc/g++ 7.3.1 (june 2018)

**target** : Cortex M4

**C++ flags :**

```
-D${CPU_NAME}  -mcpu=${CPU} -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=${FPU} \
    -Wfatal-errors -Wall -Wno-unused-function \
    -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections \
    -fno-exceptions -fno-non-call-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit
```

**Linker flags**

```
--specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--strip-all --verbose \
    -Wl,-Map=${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}.map -T\"${LINKER_FILE}\"
```

Unused variables are optimized away thanks to `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` and `-Wl,--gc-sections`

Why is an unused static class instance not optimized away ? Am I missing on option ?

Comment: Possible side effects in constructor/destructor which should be visible (auto registration, ...).

Comment: Please, provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In substance I found the answer is  already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302848/g-does-not-show-a-unused-warning

Comment: Then you might want to answer your own question.

Comment: Or mark it as a duplicate.